# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException sometimes, other-times code runs perfectly?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to test an Arduino audio visualizer but when I run the Java visualizer 9 times out of 10 I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and other times it works perfectly. The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: number changes each time between 0 and 32.

I looked into including a second catch statement for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but that felt like putting a bandaid over a bigger problem.

```
void draw()
{
  String tempC = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (tempC != null)
  {  
  String[] items = tempC.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", 
"").replaceAll("\\s", "").split(",");

  int[] data = new int[32];

  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
      {
        try {
            data[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
             } 
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
       }
    background(123);
  rect (20,300,10,-(data[0]));
  rect (40,300,10,-(data[1]));
  rect (60,300,10,-(data[2]));
```

This code should take in a string (which will always contain 32 numbers) from the serial port which looks like this:
160,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,10,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,10
and turn that string into an array called data of size 32 (data[32]) where each item in the array is one of the numbers separated by a ",". Then the code will create rectangles of a height equal to the magnitude of the data. When I run this code I get the error message
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: and then some number within 0 - 32.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes `items` contains 32 elements and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Add an assert that items.length is 32.

Comment: Arduino's readStringUntil method has a timeout so it's possible it will return a string before the next \n, which therefore won't contain 32 numbers. The best thing to do is check if your string contains 32 numbers, and if not, readStringUntil again in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `item` array doesn't always have 32 values, which is the reason it sometimes throws an error and sometimes doesn't. The best way would be to initialize `data` to exact length of `items`, then loop based on the number of elements in the `items` array.

```
int[] data = new int[items.length];

for (int i = 0; i < items.length ; i++){
   try {
       data[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
   } 
   catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, I actually had the code like that before but even with that change I am still getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException errors. There will always be a set amount of numbers in the string, so the array items and the array data should always be 32, do you have any other ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Try hardcoding `32 comma separated numbers` in `tempC`, if that works out, it means the problem is in the source `myPort`. It isn't providing complete data, or may have `\n` in between numbers.

Comment: even with hard coded values the same error occurred. Here is how I wrote it: 
 ' String tempC = ("160,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,10,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,10");'

Comment: This works for me, try printing out `i` to see if there's a specific index, or random `IndexOutOfBounds`. Also check which array `data` or `items` is throwing this error

Comment: I ended up putting in a hard coded size of 100 and the code started running perfectly. Not sure what I was doing wrong but thank you for the help! This is only a temporary simulator for the code so this will work great for what is needed